# Calling fork before main

Tags: c++, c, fork, posix, language-lawyer

Does the POSIX standard allow calling `fork()` before `main()` - for example, in a C++ `static` instance, or in a `__attribute__((constructor))` C function?

Comment: `__atribute__` is not standard C, nor POSIX. And C++ is a **different** language.

Comment: Why would you even *want*  to call `fork()` before `main()`?

Answer (score 7):

There is no indication in the `fork` manpage that it's prohibited, nor can I think of a reason for it to be.

Indeed, there's nothing special about `main` as far as POSIX is concerned; it's just that C chooses to begin its programs in a function with that name, and C++ sort of almost nearly does the same. But as far as POSIX is concerned, once your process is up, your process is up. It could have been written in any old language, and `fork` would still have to work.

In C (*not* C++!) it is impossible for *you* to write code that executes before `main` (because initialisers for `static` variables must be constant in that context), so for C it's a bit of a moot point. However, stepping outside of the C abstraction for a moment, there's still nothing in POSIX stopping your compiler vendor from including code in the C runtime that performs a `fork` before entering `main`. Recall that the "true" entrypoint is not actually `main`; the "true" entrypoint does some library initialisations and whatnot before invoking `main` to begin your part of the program.

Answer (score 5):

> Does the POSIX standard allow calling `fork()` before `main()` [...] ?

It depends on what you mean.

### C programs

POSIX, through its incorporation of the C standard, specifies that C program startup occurs when the environment (operating system) calls `main()`.  The POSIX-defined semantics of the C program start at that point; by definition, they do not include prior calls to any other function.  If any such calls in fact occur then they are not part of "the program" in this sense, so ***the program*** cannot call `fork()` before `main()`.

On the other hand, POSIX does not explicitly forbid the process in which a C program runs to execute `fork()` or any other function prior to the commencement of the defined C semantics.  In the sense that what is not forbidden is allowed, POSIX does allow it.  If your question is about whether GCC's `__attribute__((constructor))` or similar facilities violate POSIX then no, they don't, though their behavior is not defined by POSIX.

On the third hand, POSIX does not *affirmatively* allow it, and does not define any way for C source code to specify that it should happen.  If your question is about whether POSIX defines a specific facility that `__attribute__((constructor))` or similar facilities leverage to provide their advertised behavior, or whether it requires that conforming systems must provide a mechanism by which such facilities can operate, then no, it doesn't.  Not providing such a mechanism would not inherently cause a system to fail to conform to POSIX.

### C++ programs

POSIX is defined in terms of the shell command language and ISO C.  It does not require implementations to provide any C++ support at all, but of course it does not forbid it, either.  Thus, the second and third paragraphs of the previous section apply to all aspects of C++ programs.

For what it's worth, however, like C, C++ specifies that programs start in `main()`.  This has similar meaning in C++ as in C, but unlike C, C++ implementations *may* provide mechanisms by which user-provided code can be made to run before the first statement of `main()`.  Specifically, the constructor for a variable with static duration *may* run before the first statement of `main()` is executed, but whether it does so is implementation-defined (C++11, 3.6.2/4).  In this sense, therefore, it is implementation-defined whether the C++ program semantics can include a call to `fork()` before the first statement of `main()`.

Note also that the C++ standard is carefully worded to avoid speaking to whether such initializations can be before `main()` is *entered* -- that's probably immaterial, but there are at least a couple of ways in which it would be possible to tell the difference.

### Other programs

POSIX has even less to say about other kinds of programs than it has to say about C++ programs, except for shell scripts.  Of course, shell scripts generally don't have a `main()` at all, and they have no direct access to the C library by which to explicitly `fork()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use fork from the moment the libc is fully loaded and initialized.

A simple test program can show this is true :

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 void before(void) __attribute__ (( constructor ));
 void after(void) __attribute__ (( destructor ));

 int main(void)
 {
   puts("main");

   return 0;
 }

 void before(void)
 {
   puts("before");
 }

 void after(void)
 {
   puts("after");
 }
```

The output is :

```
 $ LD_DEBUG=files ./a.out
      26032:    
      26032:    file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by ./a.out [0]
      26032:    file=libc.so.6 [0];  generating link map
      26032:      dynamic: 0x00007f58c7703ba0  base: 0x00007f58c7341000   size: 0x00000000003c8a00
      26032:        entry: 0x00007f58c7361950  phdr: 0x00007f58c7341040  phnum:                 10
      26032:    
      26032:    
      26032:    calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      26032:    
      26032:    
      26032:    initialize program: ./a.out
      26032:    
 before
      26032:    
      26032:    transferring control: ./a.out
      26032:    
 main
      26032:    
      26032:    calling fini: ./a.out [0]
      26032:    
 after
```

Library loaded, initializations done, so it must be safe to use fork with a construtor tagged function.

Comment: The question is about what POSIX *allows*.  That your program exhibits the desired behavior in a particular environment does not speak to whether POSIX allows the behavior, and in no way does it prove that the practice it demonstrates is "safe" in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: the question is much more simpler, the question is «can I safelly use library (POSIX or stdc or whatever) functions before main using the constructor attribute defined by gcc or clang in a POSIX environment». It's much more about the loading mechanism rather than a POSIX question.

Comment: Considering that the question text starts with "Does the POSIX standard allow [...]" and that it is tagged [language-lawyer], I am a bit at a loss as to how you can interpret it as not being about the provisions of POSIX.